# C# / LINQ(?) - Joining two DataTables (without SQL!)

Tags: c#, linq, join, datatable

I have two Datatables that (inside the SQLS DB) have a relationship (let's call them dtStock and dtSpec, where dtSpec.ItemTypeID = dtStock.ID). I am pulling these from the DB separately (using SqlClient) so I can update them both with CommandBuilders.

I have a control that wants to see a single Datatable (dtJob).

How do I join them so that when I update dtJob using the control, dtSpec and dtStock get updated as well? I'm guessing this will involve LINQ...

This sounds like it should be a pretty simple thing to do, but most of the examples I've found seem to COPY the data to a new table rather than refer to the original data, or require a lot of code to accomplish (e.g. rewriting the CopyToDataTable method to deal with joins). Maybe my Google-fu is just rubbish.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I canned this DataTable idea and went with a List (even with the higher quantity of code required) - after some thought I discovered that joining two Datatables isn't what I really wanted to do anyway, things were somewhat more complex. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the schema of the `dtJob` [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) is the sum of the `dtStock` and `dtSpec` schemas you might want to look at the [**DataTable.Merge**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtk78t63.aspx) method to propagate the changes from `dtJob` to the two other tables.

Here's an example:

```
dtStock.Merge(dtJob, preserveChanges: false, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
dtSpec.Merge(dtJob, preserveChanges: false, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
```

Note that in this sample I've used [named arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx), which are only available in C# 4.0, in order to make the method call more readable.

Here's a more complete example:

```
var firstTable = new DataTable();
firstTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FirstTableId", typeof(int)));
firstTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FirstTableName", typeof(string)));
firstTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SecondTableId", typeof(int)));

var secondTable = new DataTable();
secondTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SecondTableId", typeof(int)));
secondTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SecondTableName", typeof(string)));

var joinedTable = new DataTable();
joinedTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FirstTableId", typeof(int)));
joinedTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FirstTableName", typeof(string)));
joinedTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SecondTableId", typeof(int)));
joinedTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SecondTableName", typeof(string)));

joinedTable.Rows.Add(1, "FirstTableRow1", 1, "SecondTableRow1");
joinedTable.Rows.Add(2, "FirstTableRow2", 1, "SecondTableRow1");
joinedTable.Rows.Add(3, "FirstTableRow3", 2, "SecondTableRow2");

firstTable.Merge(joinedTable, false, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
secondTable.Merge(joinedTable, false, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
```

**Related resources:**

- [DataTable.Merge Method (DataTable, Boolean, MissingSchemaAction)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtk78t63.aspx)

Comment: I can't get this to work - I get "Target table dtJoined missing definition for column ItemType_ID" at the first merge line, but ItemType_ID IS definitely there (I looped through the source tables' columns and populated the joined table's columns from them)...or am I misunderstanding the error? (I changed the 'MissingSchemaAction' so I could see the error, previously it was returning a blank table)

Comment: @Jez Clark Can you post the schemas of the three tables?